# Dev Express Edit Grid page double numbers

Tags: gridview, devexpress

I have a devExpress grid page with edit capabilities.  One text field has a phone number format.  When a user tries to enter the phone number, it will enter double numbers, such as, if hte number was area code 804, it will enter (880)044-xxxx.  I have my application on a few servers, its only on one server this issue occurs.  Any updates have not fixed the issue.  weird it only happens one server and manually updating working code won't fix it.

Edit:

```
 <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn FieldName="Phone" VisibleIndex="9">
 <PropertiesTextEdit><MaskSettings Mask="(999) 000-0000" /><ValidationSettings>
<RequiredField IsRequired="True" ErrorText="Phone number is required" />
</ValidationSettings>
</PropertiesTextEdit>
</dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>
```

Code for the gridview item, where the mask treats it as a phone number.  thus the format (***)***-____ on creating a new item.  For whatever reason, the application allows multiple numbers typed, as stated above.  Works as expected in development, copying new code to production server does not change the results.  is this a devExpress?

Edit: Adjusted the text box to remove the mask.  Time does not allow me to investigate this any further. Added validators to allow only telephone numbers, without the mask format.

Comment: I think you should provide more information and some lines of code here.

Comment: I hope that clears it up.  I don't think it's a devExpress issue, but all phone numbers in my application do this.   Not in testing or on other servers but on the production server.

Answer (score 0):

Cannot find any rhyme or reason behind why this is happening. Changed the text box to only allow telephone numbers, removed the mask quality.  Weird issue...